# How to get object instead of hash from Redis cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis, to-json

I am using redis cache for saving data. I am saving data using `to_json`. How should I get data so that it becomes like before save.

Before save

```
#<CarModel id: 1, car_make_id: 1, title: "Jazz.....
```

After get using `JSON.load`

```
{"id"=>1, "car_make_id"=>"1",.........}
```

How I get so it becomes like before

Comment: By becomes like before, do you mean you want an object instead of a hash?

Comment: yes you are right :)

Comment: ***`I am saving data using to_json`*** you are saving `json` and expecting `activerecord` object..

Comment: How can I then get activerecord?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CarModel` already includes [`ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html) (assuming it is a usual Rails model), so it responds to [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) which returns the attributes as a (JSON compatible) hash:

```
car = CarModel.new(id: 1, car_make_id: 1, title: "Jazz")
#=> #<CarModel id: 1, car_make_id: 1, title: "Jazz">

json_object = car.as_json
#=> {"id"=>1, "car_make_id"=>1, "title"=>"Jazz"}
```

`as_json` is called by `to_json` to create a JSON string: (you already use this method)

```
json_string = car.to_json
#=> "{\"id\":1,\"car_make_id\":1,\"title\":\"Jazz\"}"
```

[`from_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-from_json) on the other hand parses a JSON string:

```
Car.new.from_json(json_string)
#=> #<CarModel id: 1, car_make_id: 1, title: "Jazz">
```

Note that `Car.new` creates a new instance and `from_json` simply populates its attributes. Any other states will not be serialized.

Furthermore, the object in your database might have been changed in the meantime, so it could be preferable to just store the object's id and fetch a fresh copy from the database instead.

Comment: did you mean `to_json` instead of `as_json`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon no, `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON` provides `as_json` and `from_json`. But `to_json` probably calls `as_json`. I didn't provide any further details, because that whole "storing active record objects as json in redis" looks a bit suspicious to me.

Comment: `as_json` returns a `Hash` whereas `to_json` returns a `String`, thus they both are different. `from_json` needs `String` to process, when passed `Hash` it throws `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String`. Infact, the reference you shared for [from_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-from_json) has an example which uses `to_json`..

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon you are right, I mixed up the methods. `to_json` calls `as_json`, not the other way round. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the heads-up. This happens if you don't try your solutions ;-)